# I can't get a soap message in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, service-reference

I'm getting an error:

> A security error was encountered when verifying the message

`Https` is expected when I somehow overcome this error. But I have to use `Http`.

```
EndpointAddress address2 = new EndpointAddress("http://xx.xx.xxxx/ws/test?wsdl");        
FactoryWebServiceClient client = new FactoryWebServiceClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = address2;

if (client.ClientCredentials != null)
{
    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password");
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
}

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\...\\test.xml");
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(doc.OuterXml); 

var request2 = new factoryWSUpdateData
{
   BeanXml = bytes,
   Period = 1,
   InputType = "xml",
   OutputType = "json2",
   CodeTemplate = 1
};

var result = client.create(request2);
```

Comment: Use ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol=SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11| SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13

Comment: I'm getting this error: "The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via "

Comment: Have you used above line in your code??

Comment: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            FactoryWebServiceClient service = new FactoryWebServiceClient();
          
            EndpointAddress EndpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://xxxxxx/ws/test?wsdl");
            service = new FactoryWebServiceClient();
            service.Endpoint.Address = EndpointAddress;